# Correctly using 'in' keyword in OCAML

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ml

I have recently started working on OCAML. I am working from the book Modern Programming Languages, 2nd ed. The first chapter on ML has an exercise requiring the definition of a function `max` of type `int list -> int` to return the largest element from a list of integers. There is additionally a hint which suggests the inclusion of a helper function `maxhelper` which as a second parameter takes the current largest element. Then `max` is defined as :

```
fun max x = maxhelper (tl x, hd x)
```

I am trying to implement this in OCAML. Here is my code :

```
let max x =
  let rec maxhelper x cur_max =
    match x with
    | [] -> cur_max
    | h::t -> 
        if cur_max < h then maxhelper t h 
        else maxhelper t cur_max
  in maxhelper List.tl(x) List.hd(x)
;;
```

This results in an error I cannot understand : *This expression,* i.e. `List.tl(x)` on the last line *has type 'a list -> 'a list
but an expression was expected of type ('b -> 'c -> 'd) list*

What puzzles me is when I write the maxhelper function separately and give it arguments `[2;3;4] 1` (original list being `[1;2;3;4]`) it works correctly. Further, if I replace the arguments provided under `in` as

```
in maxhelper x 0
```

The code compiles and works correctly (for non-negative numbers). I am not sure what I have missed regarding passing arguments to `in`, or the error message I received. Mainly, why does the additional of a `List()` call cause an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing function calls as in an Algolic language, that's the basic problem I think.

Instead of

```
maxhelper List.tl(x) List.hd(x)
```

You should have

```
maxhelper (List.tl x) (List.hd x)
```

The way you wrote it, there are 4 parameters being passed to `maxhelper`: `List.tl`, `x`, `List.hd`, `x`.